# JQuery changing colour of text within columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have three columns within my webpage. On each column there are a group of three squares, the square represent a unique colour. So when the user clicks on red in column 1 the text within column 1 goes red, if blue it will go blue. If the user clicks on green within column 2 the text within column 2 will go green.

I am new to jQuery so I am not sure if I have done this right and would like to know if this is the best way of doing it.

What I want to know is there anyway of changing this so there is only one style called picker for all in each column. Also can I change the jQuery so it's not 3 seperate functions, is there a more cleaner way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this way:

```
$(function () {
    $('.picker').css('background-color', function () { //Setup the background color for each picker square.
        return $(this).data('color'); //get its color from data attribute
    }).click(function () { //Chain it through for the click event
        $(this).closest('.content').css({ //get the parent content element where color needs to be applied
            color: $(this).data('color') //set the color as that of the clicked picker.
        });
    });
});
```

#### [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hSBJd/)

In the markup provide a class called say `content` to identify its own parent content.

```
<div class='col2 content' id="test1"> <!-- You don't need id if you are using this for selcting.
```

Remove all the `picker1, 2` css rules and have just the `picker`.

Using `closest` will ensure that even if you plan to add a wrapper to your picker still your actuall content div will be selected.

- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [.css(prop,func)](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value)

Answer (score 2):

Yes! CSS selectors are all reusable! you shouldn't created multiple class' with the exact same attributes and values!

all the css classes you need `.col, .wrapper, .picker`

and then working with jQuery instead of using a div id when you want to use the code in mulitple places, work out where the element is relative to the element that fired the event or `$(this)`

check out the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/WJ5DZ/1/

Answer (score 0):

yes there is.. change all you class(picker1,picker2) to `picker` and remove the id (test,test1..)

try this

```
   $('.picker').each(function(){
      var myColor = $(this).data('color');
      $(this).css({background: myColor })
   });
  $('.picker').click(function(){
     var myColor = $(this).data('color');
     $(this).parent().css({color: myColor});

  });
```

**NOTE: you don't need `click` event inside `each` loop**

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FfvWL/1/)